# How to enable Snaplines in VS2010 Winforms?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

HI

I just migrated from VS2008 to VS2010 Pro. When I use windows controls in forms in Visual Basic, the snap lines to other control does not appear to help to place the the controls with others. I checked the the option, all was checked and set to be enabled but still no guide lines!!
Any ideas?

Regards

Comment: Works fine on my machine, never heard anybody complain about it before.  This must be environmental.

Comment: It Works OK with Windows 7 but it does not in windows XP!! I do not know what is the problem!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem after extensive searches on the internet. The Snaplines are visible after I updated the Video Card Driver for my machine!
I found the solution in this webpage:

http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/337354/form-designer-snap-lines-and-control-visibility-problems

Answer (score 1):

I found a different solution. I had the same problem running Visual Studio 2010 professional on windows XP Professional (Service Pack 3). Updating my graphics driver was not possible (Intel 82945G express), so I tried lowering the color quality in the display settings from "Highest (32 bit)" to "Medium (16 bit)" and it worked!
Control Panel, Display, Settings Tab, Color Quality.